# Share only part of code with another computer which uses a different kind of project

Tags: git, bitbucket

Let's assume that I've created on bitbucket an Android project repository. I wanna to work on part of the project, let's say on a folder and wanna to share only that folder with another developer who uses Xcode Objective-C project. Then I wanna to share the whole android project with another developer too.
Is this possible ? 
How can I proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the information in the documentation of [gitcvs-migration](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitcvs-migration.html) in the `Setting Up a Shared Repository` part.

Comment: The "Setting Up a Shared Repository" part of what?

Comment: In the link I gave: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitcvs-migration.html